# Hyperboloid with different sheets?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I just took a quiz and have a couple basic questions because I am too anxious to wait a week for my score.

My questions are:

1) *I put hyperboloid of one sheet for this
$$
\frac{(x-1)^{2}}{2^{2} } - \frac{(y)^{2}}{2^{2}} + \frac{(z)^{2}}{2^{2}} = 1
$$

2) *I put hyperboloid of one sheet again, but feeling like it's two sheets.
$$
\frac{-(x)^{2}}{2^{2} } + \frac{(y)^{2}}{2^{2}} + \frac{(z)^{2}}{2^{2}} + 10 = 0 
$$

Comment: There is only one negative term and there is a constant in both of them. The first one is hyperboloid in one sheet. The second one, bring 10 over and divide by -10. You will get two negative letter terms. meaning 2 sheets

Answer (score 0):

The general equation for a hyperboloid of one sheet is 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$
For $1)$, the equation is precisely this form (with the roles of $y$ and $z$ reversed so that the axis of symmetry is the $y$ axis).
The general equation for a hyperboloid of two sheets is 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$
Your equation is
$$\frac{-x^2}{2^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} + \frac{z^2}{2^2} + 10= 0 \implies \frac{x^2}{10*2^2} - \frac{y^2}{10*2^2} - \frac{z^2}{10*2^2} = 1$$
shiwch is indeed an equation of a hyperboloid of two sheets (comparing it with the general equation).

Comment: But how do two negative signs form?

Comment: Subtract $10$ from both sides of your equation.  Then divide by $-10$.